# App not compatible with buildpack while push to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have tried all the solutions related to this issue. Nothing worked for me. I am using Django and I put Procfile,requirements.txt, runtime.txt file where manage.py is located. As I know this is the root directory of my project.

Can anyone plz help me out?

```
git push -f heroku master
Enumerating objects: 718, done.
Counting objects: 100% (718/718), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (522/522), done.
Writing objects: 100% (718/718), 11.44 MiB | 314.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 718 (delta 184), reused 682 (delta 172)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku-community/apt.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to ewallet-food.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/ewallet-food.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ewallet-food.git'
```

Comment: You don't have an `Aptfile`.

Comment: I have apt file in the same directory where manage.py is

Comment: It needs to be in the root directory and it needs to be named `Aptfile`